# JSON Format Issue with response

Tags: javascript, php, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to work with the bootstrap typeahead plugin but I need to get my JSON to output correctly.

Per the last example on this page it appears you can use more than just a `key->value` in the JSON response: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Here is what my PHP code looks like:

```
$objDB = new DB;
    $xml = $objDB->setStoredProc('shadowGetEmp')
                -> setParam("ntid", $query)
                -> execStoredProc()
                -> parseXML();


        foreach($xml->emp as $emp){

            $name = $emp->FirstName .' '. $emp->LastName;
            $qid = $emp->QID;
            $empID = $emp->EmpID;

            $users[] = array('name'=> $name, 'qid'=> $qid, 'empID'=> $empID);
        }

     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($users);
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "qid": {
        "0": "Q1234"
    },
    "empID": {
        "0": "123"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Bob Jones",
    "qid": {
        "0": "Q5678"
    },
    "empID": {
        "0": "456"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Mike James",
    "qid": {
        "0": "Q2233"
    },
    "empID": {
        "0": "789"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Harry Potter",
    "qid": {
        "0": "Q2212"
    },
    "empID": {
        "0": "223"
    }
}]
```

How can I format the response to a correct JSON output?

I think its because of the associative array but not sure how to include more than just a key/value and format the JSON.

Comment: What's wrong with that JSON? Looks fine to me...

Comment: why are there 0 values in qid and empid but not name?

Comment: I see, so it should be an array instead?

Comment: just trying to make it like http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/l.json

but instead of tokens just another value.

Comment: so name, qid and empid are technically the keys and the values need to be in their respective place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$emp->QID` and `$emp->EmpID` are returning an array with one element.

Either fix the code that assigns those variables in the `$emp` instance (better, seems like those should just be number/id values, not an array) or compensate for it here (dirty solution, but will work).